# How to copy and paste a flow in dialogflow cx?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I want to create an agent with two flows using the new version of Dialogflow (CX), in some ways this 2 flows are very similar. That's why instead of creating from scratch all the pages of a flow i was looking if it was possible to copy and paste a flow and then make some changes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. However, in Dialogflow CX intents can be reused, which would speed up your progress as compared to Dialogflow ES.
Additionally, you can create [Route Groups](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#route-group) to deal with Routes that should exist at multiple parts in your conversation tree. That should take care of some duplication!

Answer (score 1):

Two weeks ago Dialogflow released Flow Import/Export.

You can now click on a flow -> Export to file
Click on '+' to add a new flow, and now you can choose import, choose the file you just imported and voilá, you got yourself a copy.

Heads up that the copying of parameters, entities and intents is a bit funky so you may need to remove trailing numbers that may be added to duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot for answering! I didn't know about Route Groups, which seems to be a valid alternative to solve my problem! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have been helpful! On Stackoverflow you would not make a new answer to respond to another one. Please use 'add a comment' for that. If you would like to say thanks, the best way to do so is accept and upvote the answer. Happy hacking!